# Ruby on rails - how to get attribute parameters of update or create in AR model callbacks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Here's my ActiveRecord model looks like

```
class History < ApplicationRecord
  validates_date :start_date, :allow_nil => true
  validates_date :end_date, :allow_nil => true
  validates :duration, :allow_nil => true, :numericality => { :greater_than => 0 }

  before_save do
    puts self.start_date
  end
end
```

When I try to create or update a History object, I get the `start_date` in the console, but even though I don't pass `start_date` to the `update` parameters, I can see the old value from the db.

```
history = History.create({start_date:"2020-11-20"})    # 2020-11-20 is printed in console
history.update!({"end_date": "2020-11-25"})            # 2020-11-20 is also printed in console
```

How can I check whether `start_date` is not passed to the `update` method in the ActiveRecord model callbacks?

Comment: `before_save` callback method is called both for `create` and `update`

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html

Comment: and that's why is printed. it doesn't matter if it's passed or not to create or update, it's an attribute of the history object and you can print it

Comment: @Ursus I know this is very special case. What I want to do is to modify the other attribute before creating or updating based on the values passed from the UI and old values in the database. What is the handy and smart way to do this?

Comment: sorry, it's not clear to me. be more clear on what you want to accomplish please

Comment: @Ursus I need to get the values being passed to create and update method as well as the old values in the db(if it's update) before the actual saving is done

Comment: try to print `start_date_was` and `end_date_was`. you can even use `start_date_changed?` and `end_date_changed?` methods

Comment: maybe this can help you

Comment: already tried both, if `start_date` is not passed to the `update` method, `start_date` is the same as `start_date_was`. I was hoping `start_date` would be `nil`, but no. And if I pass the same value for `start_date` as in the db, `start_date_changed` is `False`, where I expect `True` because the parameter is passed anyways.

Comment: it's very hard for me, I don't get what you want to do

Answer (score 0):

After read your conversation. I think you need this method: `end_date_came_from_user?`

It's check if end_date came from user input.